# How to investigate SMTP mail sent?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I follow this doc to enable wso2is to sent email for self user registration :

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Self+Sign+Up+and+Account+Confirmation

But I am not receiving any email.
I would like to investigate but there is no message in the log althoug I add the following logger in log4j.properties :

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis2.transport.mail=DEBUG
log4j.logger.com.sun.mail=DEBUG
```

And also put `-Dmail.debug=true` in server.sh but nothing about smtp error or mail execption shows up in the log... 
How can I fix it and investiguate ?
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a gmail account for sending emails, you have to go to [1] and select "Turn on" option for allowing 3rd party apps to send emails using gmail.

However if that is not the case, you can enable debug logs for following.

log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt=DEBUG

and identify the issue based on the logs.

[1] https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: Thanks for the answer the problem was because I want email confirmation but not account lock, and disabling account lock make the mail not been sent...

Answer (score 0):

It might even be that a virusscanner blocks the gmail port (587) for spamming.

Using DevNullSmtp.jar helps to see what is going out.

See also

https://www.yenlo.com/blog/wso2easy-errors-sending-otp-emails-in-wso2-identity-server